# Data Source configuration on WebSphere 7

Tags: java, websphere, datasource

I am working on WebSphere application server recently. And now i have to use DataSourceConnectionProvider for it. So i know how to configure it for JBOSS but I need the configuration info about WAS 7.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are decent articles about how to do this in the Info Center, for example [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tdat_tccrtprovds.html). As a first attempt use the admin console in conjunction with the documentation in the Info CentreThe details will very depending upon the version of WAS, the edition of WAS and the database you're using. Make sure you go to the right Info Center.

Later you will probably find scripting to be useful.